# Is this wrong: "These are expensive engagement rings. Having said that, the rings are very glory."?

Tags: sentence-construction

I am trying to mimic this sentence from a book:

> *It's an expensive restaurant. Having said that, the food is very good.*

Is this wrong?

> These are expensive engagement rings. Having said that, the rings are very glory.

I tried to make a new sentence by altering *restaurant* (singular) by *engagement rings* (plural). I want have a better sentence. Is this correct?

Comment: 'Glory' is not an adjective.

Comment: There's glory for you.

Comment: @JamesK  Your comment deserves a reference: https://quotes.yourdictionary.com/author/lewis-carroll/6884

Comment: This is a request for proofreading, which is off-topic here. I'm closing this question to new answers

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could use this, but be careful.

**Glory** is a noun: the sense of glory

**Glorious** is an adjective: to have glory

So, you would say:

*These are expensive engagement rings. Having said that, the rings are very glorious.*

*Note: as a comment says, I would recommend not saying 'very glorious', rather 'glorious' since it sounds more natural*

Comment: Usually, *glorious* has an intense meaning. It doesn't go well with *very*. (Are they very glorious, or just slightly glorious?)

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty I agree with what you say, but for purposes of simplicity I decided not to add that. Not sure if it should though.